# On click, blur my content behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Is there a way when I click my menu button (and menu is revealed) my content in the background has a blur on it and when clicked again, the content goes back to normal?**

**Currently working with this HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a target="_parent" href="">A</a></li>
      <li><a target="_parent" href="">B</a></li>
      <li><a target="_parent" href="">C</a></li>
      <li><a target="_parent" href="">D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**This CSS:**

```
$square: 50px;
* {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
body {
  background: #111;
  font: 300 14px Consolas, system, monospace;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed; 
  height: $square;
  width: $square;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  @include transition(all 250ms ease-in-out);
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    @include transform(translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%));
    opacity: 0;
    @include transition(all 250ms linear 250ms);
    pointer-events: none;
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      li a {

        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        &:hover {
          background: #000;
          color: #fff;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .line {
    height: 5px;
    width: $square - 10;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: ($square/2)-(5/2);
    left: ($square - ($square - 10))/2;
    @include transition(all 250ms linear);
    &:after, &:before {
      content: ' ';
      height: 5px;
      width: $square - 10;
      background: #000;
      position: absolute;
      @include transition(all 250ms linear);
    }
    &:before {
      top: -10px;
    }
    &:after {
      bottom: -10px;
    }
  }
  &.active {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    nav {
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: all;
    }
    .line {
      background: transparent;
      &:before {
        background: #000;
        @include transform(rotate(-405deg));
        top: 0px;
      }
      &:after {
        background: #000; 
        @include transform(rotate(405deg));
        bottom: 0px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**This JS:**

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.removeClass('active');
  }
  else {
    $this.addClass('active');    
  }


});
```

**I would be very grateful if anyone could help. Cheers**

Comment: You should add an overlay every time your menu appears. Once you have the overlay, you can style it however you want.

Comment: I want to create more depth in my website and blur the content behind too

Comment: Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/967q5L1d/).

Comment: Is this what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/h7ygeewh/2/

Answer (score 1):

Example on codepen here including:

```
content {filter:blur(5px);
```

http://codepen.io/simoncmason/pen/ogoPXK

This example blurs the content behind, however the browser support for this isn't complete (http://caniuse.com/#search=filter) no i.e.

But, you could use just an opaque filter - I have included this in the example) and better browsers get the blur - or for more support use an inline blurred SVG, or maybe a js effect such as http://blurjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/967q5L1d/).

Basically you just need to append a dynamic div (or insert manually) and set give it a `fixed` position with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` with a `background & opacity`.

However it must be outside of the `.menu` container or your `.menu` contents will also have an opacity.

Answer (score 0):

You can always search http://css-tricks.com for stylesheet related help as they have a good library.

You should be looking at the **CSS FILTERS** to create the blur effect upon clicking the menu and then turning it back to normal on release.

I had this link in my library that clearly shows what you are trying to do [JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wkgnj851/1/)

and here part of the stylesheet where you have the blur

```
This class is added to the container 
(#blurMe) when the sidebar is open.
-----------------------------------*/
.blurred {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-filter: url(#blur);
          filter: url(#blur);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='10');
}
```